# Add custom name of Export Excel in downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#btnExport").click(function (e) {
window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
e.preventDefault();
});
```

I am using above code for export the excel. This is working fine. Problem is file is downloading by file name "download". I want to give the custom name.

Comment: https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin/issues/13

Comment: @Aditi i have modified my answer to run window.open in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Below Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#btnExport',function(e) {
        var result = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('div[id$=dvData]').html());
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.download = "download.xls"; //You need to change file_name here.
        link.href = result;
        link.click();
    });
});
```

Comment: File is downloading with custom name but when open the exce below message is coming "Excel cant open the file name Account because file format or extension is not valid"........

Comment: I have change the extension xlsx to xls. Then this is working in chrome but file is not downloading in Mozilla.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the name of your file in `name` attribute of `window.open`.

```
window.open(URL, 'your_filename', specs, replace)
```

To use `window.open` in IE there should no space between two words in `your_filename` parameter. Try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click','#btnExport',function (e) {
        var myWindow = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#dvData').html());
        myWindow.document.title = 'mywindow';
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not able use in my above code. Can you please implement in my given code?

Comment: Again not working in IE. where the custom file name will be added? Please explain clearly.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is $('#dvData').html() in your code?

Comment: This the table I am exporting means ID of the table.